# Difference between pg_column_size(table.*) and pg_column_size(table.col1) + pg_column_size (table.col2)

Tags: postgresql

From [PG DOC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html)

> pg_column_size(any) : number of bytes used to store a particular value (possibly compressed) 
>   pg_column_size shows the space used to store any individual data value

Example:

```
select pg_column_size(5::smallint);    -- 2 bytes 
select pg_column_size(5::int);         -- 4 bytes
```

With input of pg_column_size, it can be a column or row, so I created a test to check it.
Here's my test:

My table

```
CREATE TABLE index_test
(
  id integer NOT NULL,  -- 4  bytes 
  a integer,            -- 4  bytes 
  b integer,            -- 4  bytes 
  CONSTRAINT index_test_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

**1/ First query:**   **sum(pg_column_size(table.rows))**

```
with abc as 
(
 select id,a,b
 from index_test where b > 100
)
select pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(abc.*))) from abc  -- "348 kB", abc.* = record
```

And query's explanation:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=427.55..427.56 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=9.171..9.171 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  CTE abc"
"    ->  Seq Scan on index_test  (cost=0.00..180.00 rows=9902 width=12) (actual time=0.039..2.882 rows=9902 loops=1)"
"          Filter: (b > 100)"
"  ->  CTE Scan on abc  (cost=0.00..198.04 rows=9902 width=24) (actual time=0.047..7.151 rows=9902 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 9.376 ms"
```

**2/ Second query:**  **sum(pg_column_size(table.id)) + sum(pg_column_size(table.a)) + sum(pg_column_size(table.b))**

```
with abc as 
(
 select id, a, b 
 from index_test where b > 100
)
select  pg_size_pretty((sum(pg_column_size(id)))  + (sum(pg_column_size(b))) + (sum(pg_column_size(a))))
from abc  -- "116 kB"
```

And query's explanation:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=526.57..526.59 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=10.959..10.959 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  CTE abc"
"    ->  Seq Scan on index_test  (cost=0.00..180.00 rows=9902 width=12) (actual time=0.035..2.780 rows=9902 loops=1)"
"          Filter: (b > 100)"
"  ->  CTE Scan on abc  (cost=0.00..198.04 rows=9902 width=12) (actual time=0.039..5.623 rows=9902 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 11.173 ms"
```

**3/ Results:**

First query:  348 KB

Second query: 116 KB    ( pg_column_size(id) = 39 KB ...)

I thought both query had to return the same result, but size of first query = 3 * size of second query, It made me confused. In first explanation, the "width = 24 bytes / row " (instead of 12), I wondered why it is increase, I think it is the clue to the question . Until now, I can not find clear answers for my question, please help me out  .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 24 byte/row difference rings a bell: it is the same size as the row header in tables and indexes.  What I did not realize up until your question is that the same header size applies apparently to every row you return in a query:

```
SELECT pg_column_size((1::integer, 2::smallint));
 pg_column_size 
────────────────
             30
```

but

```
SELECT pg_column_size(1::integer) + pg_column_size(1::smallint) AS pg_column_size;
 pg_column_size 
────────────────
              6
```

When passing a row to `pg_column_size()`, it calculates the size of the whole row, including the header.

Now playing a bit further with this, there are some interesting facts you can find.

For example, one can check the difference caused by padding the columns up to the nearest 4 bytes (where k is a positive integer):

```
SELECT pg_column_size((1::smallint, 2::integer));
 pg_column_size 
────────────────
             32
```

Here we got two more bytes than in the first example, the remaining 2 bytes after the smallint got 'wasted'.  This may be important when choosing the order of columns in huge tables - for example, we can squeeze something into that 'empty' space:

```
SELECT pg_column_size((1::smallint, FALSE, FALSE, 2::integer));
 pg_column_size 
────────────────
             32
```

The other important thing is that columns that have NULL as a value have zero size here:

```
SELECT pg_column_size((NULL::smallint, 2::integer));
 pg_column_size 
────────────────
             28
```

In contrast, you'll get NULL as a result when trying to add up the column individually:

```
SELECT pg_column_size(NULL::smallint) +  pg_column_size(2::integer) AS pg_column_size;
 pg_column_size 
────────────────
           NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @dezso, I understand what you said above. If we select pg_column_size (row), it will plus + 24 header bytes per row .  But why, we do not need to calculate size of header, we just want to see size of columns  ? I am not clear in this point . And "padding the columns up to the nearest 4k bytes (where k is a positive integer)" is interesting, I just know it.

Comment: @luannnh Now that you cited it, I realized that I had written 4k instead of 4.  Fixed.