# Why is the per-row size returned by pg_table_size greater than pg_column_size(row)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, database-size

I have a table with only integer and smallint columns, adding up to 20 bytes. `pg_column_size` reports 44. This is expected due to the 24-byte per-row overhead, as explained in [Difference between pg_column_size(table.*) and pg_column_size(table.col1) + pg_column_size (table.col2)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68455/difference-between-pg-column-sizetable-and-pg-column-sizetable-col1-pg-c)

However, if I divide `pg_table_size` by the number of rows I get ~53 bytes per row, even with hundreds of millions of rows. Where are these extra 9 bytes coming from?

I can reproduce this even with one integer column:

```
drop table if exists anint;

create table anint
as
select generate_series
from generate_series(1, 10000000);

select pg_column_size(e.*) -- 28
from anint e
limit 1;

select n_live_tup as row_count_estimate, -- 10000000
    pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size(relid)) as table_size, -- 346 MB
    case when n_live_tup = 0 then null else pg_table_size(relid) / cast(n_live_tup as float) end as table_bytes_per_row -- 36.2561536
from pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables io
join pg_catalog.pg_stat_user_tables s using (relid)
where io.schemaname = 'public' and io.relname = 'anint'
```

This returns ~36 bytes/row, not 28. (Tested on PostgreSQL 14.1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the layout of a PostgreSQL table page: [image: table page layout]

The row size that you are measuring is the `Item`, but there is also the `ItemId` (“line pointer”) that is described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html#PAGE-TABLE):

> ItemIdData: Array of item identifiers pointing to the actual items. Each entry is an (offset,length) pair. 4 bytes per item.

In addition, there is the page header and alignment padding to account for, and there will always be some free space left in each block (anything that is to small to fit another row). Together that may be enough to explain the difference. You can use the [pageinspect](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html) extension to examine data pages in detail.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems that PG adds overhead of at least 28 bytes per row - quite a bit more than I was expecting. :(

Comment: It's being actively worked in - see zheap and/or (PostgreSQL)  table access methods